# Input shape for LSTM

Tags: dataframe, machine-learning, lstm

The shape of my input data set (numpy array) is `(74544, 10)`, which means I have 10 features and 74544 rows/samples and i am bit confuse how to convert that to 3D LSTM input shape

will be as : `reshape(74544, 10, 1)`
or `(74544,1, 10)`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Input shape for LSTM will be reshaped by  : (1,74544,10)

Where, 1 is batch_size. 74544 are the timesteps, and 10 are your features.

Answer (score -1):

It should be reshape(74544,10,1).

Comment: In this case, the LSTM considers this as 74544 are the batch_size, 10 are timesteps, 1 is your features. This would be wrong.